# Blender 2.8 Grease Pencil - How to draw continuous lines

Tags: grease-pencil

How can i draw continuous lines in blender 2.8 grease pencil?
I can click on draw shape - select line but then i can only draw one line between two points i want to be able to carry on adding more points and for the line to be connected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To draw a polygon (i.e. a set of connected lines), use the `Poly` function. It's right next to the `Line` button:

[image: poly button]

Comment: Hi, I do not have that option ... please see the picture i edited my question with after your answer - i definitely do not have the poly option...

Comment: @Kommando1980 oh, your interface seems to be different, maybe because you're using the experimental 2.8. See if you can get the Tool Shelf in the `3D view` by using `View` > `Tool Shelf`. Then, you will hopefully have the same options in the `Grease Pencil` tab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I could not find such an option unfortunately in the 2.8 build. I am trying to learn blender using the experimental build since i am not doing any production work yet. if you do however find that option in the 2.8 build please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can go to *Edit Mode* and each frame extrude the last vertex, then it looks like the line is continuous.